# if value of span true radio button automatically checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to checkbox value checked when span text "True"
the blow example work perfectly on radio button click then span value goes to "true" or "false".
**Code**

```
$('table').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    $(this).next('span').text('True').closest('td')
           .siblings().find('span').text('False');
});
```

**Html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
<td> <input  type='radio' name='attandance' ><span>False</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i want if the span value true then radio button automatically checked .
[image: here is out put]

Answer (score 0):

Use `:contains()` to find the spans that contain `True`, then check the adjacent radio button.

```
$("table").find("span:contains(True)").prev(":radio").prop("checked", true);
```